# dplyr mutate colnames in pipe function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data %>%
  left_join(., panel_info, by = "PANID") %>%
  left_join(., prod_0106, by = "UPC") %>%
  left_join(., prod_0106sz, by = "UPC") %>%
  left_join(., trips, by = "PANID") %>%
  mutate(colnames(.) = gsub(" ", "", colnames(.)))
```

Everything works except the last line. The `df` data frame has not been created previously. So using the pipe function I am trying to join all the data together and finally remove all the blank spaces in the column names of the joined together data.

However, the following error occurs;

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `gsub(" ", "", colnames(.))` must be length 20056 (the number of rows) or one, not 106
```

Which I assume is due to the `(.)` in the `mutate()` part of the code. Just want to see where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Use rename_all instead

Comment: I always use `janitor::clean_names()` for that task. It 'handles' almost every 'incorrect' colname

Comment: See `rename_at()`

Comment: `mutate` create a new column, which in this case would be called `colnames(.)`. You want the `rename` function.

Comment: you can also pipe into an anonymous function that returns the changed df: `%>% {colnames(.) = gsub(" ", "", colnames(.)); .}`

Comment: `rename_all(., gsub(" ", "", colnames(.)))` is not working @struggles solution works but I am interested in how it can be applied to `rename_all` also.

Comment: Why even make it part of the chain? There's nothing lost by ending your chain after all the joins and then on a new line just use `names(df) <- gsub(' ', '', names(df))`

Comment: @user113156 in your `rename_all` call, you need to signal an anonymous function with `~` before `gsub`. Also, in the anonymous function, `.` will be a character vector of names, so no need to call `colnames()` on it.

Comment: This is a great use case for `setNames()`, which can be used with a pipe (also see `purrr::set_names()`).  You can do `%>% setNames(gsub(" ", "", colnames(.)))`

Comment: @brittenb because piping is fun

Answer (score 9):

You can also set `colnames` in a dplyr pipe by piping into `` `colnames<-()` `` which is the generic form of the function called when you do `colnames(df) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')`:

```
iris %>%
    `colnames<-`(gsub('Length', 'LENGTH', names(.))) %>%
    head

  Sepal.LENGTH Sepal.Width Petal.LENGTH Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 4):

As from the comments, there are a number of options. A couple I think fit in well with chaining:

```
library(dplyr)

> iris %>% rename_all(~gsub('Length', 'LENGTH', .x)) %>% head()

  Sepal.LENGTH Sepal.Width Petal.LENGTH Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

> iris %>% setNames(gsub('Length', 'LENGTH', names(.))) %>% head()

  Sepal.LENGTH Sepal.Width Petal.LENGTH Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```